# Local quadratic approximation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation, regression

I wanted to implement some penalized regression parameter estimation algorithm by Fan&Li (http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~rli/research/penlike.pdf, section 3.3, [1]), but cannot catch the idea of some details. More specifically, I don't quite understand how local quadratic approximation is derived.

Assume that $p(x)$ is concave penalty function s.t. $p(0)=0$ and $p$ is not differentiable at origin.
It is stated that given initial value $x_0$ we can approximate

$\left[p(|x|)\right]'=p'(|x|)\text{sgn}(x)\approx \lbrace{p'(|x_0|)/|x_0|\rbrace}x$, $(1)$

when $x\neq 0$ (actually it should be that both $x,x_0\neq 0$, shouldn't it?)
and the approximation leads to

$p(|x|)\approx p(|x_0|)+\tfrac{1}{2}\lbrace{p'(|x_0|)/|x_0|)\rbrace}(x^2-x_0^2)$, 
for $x\approx x_0$. $(2)$

I think that $(1)$ follows from assumption that if $x\approx x_0$ then

$p'(|x|)\text{sgn}(x)/x\approx p'(|x_0|)/|x_0|$.

But how one gets to $(2)$? Why the second term in Taylor approximation is lost and how is second derivative approximated?

[1]: Jianqing Fan, Runze Li. [Variable Selection via Nonconcave Penalized
Likelihood and its Oracle Properties](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~rli/research/penlike.pdf).  Journal of the American Statistical Association, December 2001, vol 96 no 456, pp.1348-1360.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) follows from a case analysis, according to whether $x$ is positive or negative: thus
$$\text{sign}(x) = {x \over |x|}$$
if $x \ne 0$.  Applying this, we find
$$p'(|x|) \cdot \text{sign}(x) \approx p'(|x|) \times {x \over |x|} \approx p'(|x_0|) \times {x \over |x_0|},$$
which justifies (1).

---

(2) follows from a first-order Taylor series approximation for $x^2-x_0^2$.  Notice that if $x \approx x_0$, we have
$$x^2 - x_0^2 \approx 2 (x-x_0) x_0.$$
(Why?  Because when $\epsilon \approx 0$, we have $(x_0+\epsilon)^2 \approx x_0^2 + 2 \epsilon x_0$, thus $(x_0 + \epsilon)^2 - x_0^2 \approx 2 \epsilon x_0$.)
In other words,
$$x-x_0 \approx {x^2 - x_0^2 \over 2x_0} \approx {x^2 - x_0^2 \over 2x}.$$
Now we can use this to derive (2).  By a Taylor series expansion, we know
$$p(|x|) \approx p(|x_0|) + (x-x_0) \cdot p'(|x_0|) \cdot \text{sign}(x_0).$$
Plug in (1), and we find
$$p(|x|) \approx p(|x_0|) + (x-x_0) \times p'(|x_0|) \times {x \over |x_0|}.$$
Finally, plug in our approximation for $x-x_0$ and find
$$p(|x|) \approx p(|x_0|) + {x^2 - x_0^2 \over 2x} \times p'(|x_0|) \times {x \over |x_0|},$$
which simplifies to
$$p(|x|) \approx p(|x_0|) + {x^2 - x_0^2 \over 2 |x_0|} \times p'(|x_0|),$$
which matches what you listed in (2).

In other words, we're still approximating $p(|x|)$ using only a first-order Taylor series approximation, not a second-order Taylor series approximation.

Yes, it's ugly, and there's probably a cleaner derivation.